# Variable written as nil when passed through segue

Tags: ios, uikit, uistoryboardsegue

this is my code

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var madLibInput: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "completedSenteceSegue" {
            
            let nvc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            nvc.passedInput = madLibInput.text
        }
    }
}
```

the other viewcontroller is this:

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myUncleWantsToText: UILabel!
    var passedInput: String!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myUncleWantsToText.text = "My uncle wants to go to the \(passedInput)" 
    }
}
```

The text ends up as "My uncle wants to go to the nil" regardless of input. Also it gives this warning: "String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?" I don't know why either of these are happening.

Comment: First thing is to try using a debugger. Add breakpoints at `nvc.passedInput = madLibInput.text` line to see if the value is actually assigned.

My best guess is that there is a typo in "completedSenteceSegue", see "sente*n*ce"

Comment: can you cross check the identifier string to which you are comparing and also put a debugger to see if the inside code if is getting executed, like ULazdins said above you might have misspelled the identifier name.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the segue identifier in the code does not match the "storyboard" one.